# Can't use PUT request on express.js for a simple JSON object data

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, put

So, I have a simple JSON object that's called "products". I can successfully add and remove products, but I can not manage to update one. Let's say there's "id" key for the unique id, and "name" as the name of the product, and I only want to change the name by getting the product by id:

My server code is this:

```
app.put('/products/:id', function (req, res) {
     var product = req.body;
     var theId = req.params.id;
     var thetask = products.find(theId);
     product.save({
         name: thetask.name
     }); 
});
```

My PUT request is:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/products/someid '{"name": "newname"}'
```

Comment: What is `products`?  What is that `.find()` function?

Comment: Probably, you seacrch for  `findOneAndUpdate` function